# How to pass through all bodies in world

Tags: javascript, box2d

I need to make something in all bodies of a world. But I don't know how. I have a instance of Box2D-World world where all bodies are. I tried this:

```
var bodies = world.GetBodyList();
for(var i=0; i<bodies.length; i++)
    {
       ...
    }
```

But it doesn't work. It returns only one body, not a list how I could expect. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you describe what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: what does `world.GetBodyList()` return?

Comment: I appologize but if you know box2d library you are clear what world is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var body = world.GetBodyList(); body; body = body.GetNext())
{
    list.text+="\n";
    list.text+=(body +" " + body.GetUserData());
}
```

Shamelessly stolen from: http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=4302 . Topic is about flash, but given that it's ported everywhere similarly - that should work in JS too.